# Try to access data through null address in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

Just a curious question. What happens if i try to access data from an address that has `NULL` value.
for eg: If i have a structure pointer `ulog` which stores `NULL` and the compiler (in my case GCC) comes across `ulog->data=12` ?

I wanna know majorly if this messes with my memory, is `NULL` returned when used with control statement and what goes down with the compiler ?

Comment: The compiler won't/won't need to complain. In run-time the program will abort with  seg fault.

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and if using the pointer to write some data (like in your example assignment) then you will most likely have a crash. ***Always*** check pointers.

Comment: The compiler doesn't care, you are the programmer... The OS surely will get very disappointed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear out the terms:

- The macro `NULL` is a null pointer constant (7.19/3).
- A *null pointer constant* is either the value `0` or `(void*)0` (6.3.2.3/3).
- When a null pointer constant is assigned to a pointer of any type, the resulting pointer becomes a *null pointer* which is guaranteed to compare unequal to any other pointer (which is pointing to an object or function) (6.3.2.3/3).

You can't really know the actual representation of a null pointer on the given system. What happens if you try to access it as if it was a valid address is not specified by the standard - it is undefined behavior.

Meaning that anything can happen, including segmentation faults, bus errors, nothing at all, program starting to run amok etc etc.

Comment: @Antti Haapala Stop vandalizing my post and go read what 6.3.2.3/3 actually says :)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala No you edited in "to an object" while it says "to an object or function". Essentially meaning any pointer type.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Fine, I added some extra text...

Answer (score 1):

The compiler won't complain.

However, in runtime, you will invoke *Undefined Behavior* (UB), since you are dereferencing a NULL pointer.